# Cannot find protocol declaration for GMSMarker

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to make a marker's window clickable so it can lead to a new view

From previous stackoverflow answers, they have said to use

```
-(UIView*)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(id<GMSMarker>)marker {


}
```

However, when I use the method, xcode says "Cannot find protocol declaration for GMSMarker" and highlights

```
(id<GMSMarker>)
```

How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such protocol as GMSMarker. There is no such method as `-(UIView*)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(id<GMSMarker>)marker` in [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p) either.

`GMSMarker` is a class, not a protocol. The existing method `- (UIView *) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker` has pointer to `GMSMarker` object as second parameter, not an object conforming to GMSMarker protocol.

Comment: -(UIView*)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(id<GMSMarker>)marker was in the old version of Google maps iOS SDK. In the new version, they changed.